# Show that $(s_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

$$S_n = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + ... + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1} $$
Show that $(S_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence that it converges to limit $L$. Show that $\frac{2}{3} < L < \frac{13}{15}$

---

The question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578015/proving-that-s-n-is-cauchy)

However, the question was not answered in a way that was simple for me to understand. Additionally, in my case, I must prove that the sequence is Cauchy first. In other words, I cannot show convergence and then say use Cauchy's Criterion.

Like the original question, I am stuck at let $n = m+k$

$$|S_n - S_m|  = \left|\frac{(-1)^{m+2}}{2(m+1)-1}+ ... + \frac{(-1)^{m+k+1}}{2(m+k)-1}\right|$$

Now I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking from where you leave it:

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^{m+2}}{2(m+1)-1}+ ... + \frac{(-1)^{m+k+1}}{2(m+k)-1}\right|\le\frac{k}{2(m+1)-1}\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{}0$$

Comment: @snulty Of course. Thank you, edited.

Comment: How do you know that this inequality holds?

Comment: @BobtheBuilds The triangle inequality and taking then the biggest fraction, which is the one with the lowest denominator

Comment: The last fraction doesn't converge to $0$ if we take (*and it's allowed*) $k=m-1$ for example.

Comment: I'm not sure how you arrive at the numerator, I'd get $k$ on top.

Comment: First, @SamiBenRomdhane: the OP apparently took $\;n\;,\;\;m=n+k\;$ to try to show the Cauchy condition (which simply says the sequence of partial sums of a series converges finitely iff it is a Cauchy sequence). Then, **only** $\;m\to\infty\;$. In this case, $\;k\;$ only denotes the difference between $\;m\;$ and $\;m=n+k\;$ , and thus *obviously* putting $\;k=m-1\;$ is absurd.

Comment: @snulty, the difference between $\;2(m+k)-1\;$ and $\;2(m+1)-1\;$...but I think you're right as the numerators jump by two! Thanks, editing

Answer (score 1):

You can easily prove with the [Alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) that $(S_n)$ converge, therefore it's a Cauchy sequence.